# How do i Filter the DHCP Lease information that i export

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, dhcp

I just wrote a powershell script that will export dhcp lease information but i want to export specific information like export only IP and mac addresses in the dhcp. Instead of exporting every lease information. The one line of code i have written that exports everything is bellow.

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "HW2009-11" | Export-Csv -Path ("C:\log\new.csv")
```

Comment: How does the output of `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease` look like? Have you tried some basic things like `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "HW2009-11" | Select-Object -Property IP, mac-address`?

Comment: @Paxz Thanks very much i just did DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "HW2009-11" | Select-Object -Property IP, mac-address | Export-Csv -Path ("C:\log\new.csv") and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adress only certain properties of an object, you can use `Select-Object`. This way you can only choose the `ip`and `mac-address` like this:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "HW2009-11" | Select-Object -Property IP, mac-address
```

You can then pipe this to `Export-Csv` and it will create a .csv file with only those properties:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "HW2009-11" | Select-Object -Property IP, mac-address |  Export-Csv -Path "C:\log\new.csv"
```

If you don't know the specific properties of an object, you can just pipe the command to `Get-Member`:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease | Get-Member
```